# authorize other username using service user credentials

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

While connecting to filenet(in websphere) content engine

I have a requirement where we have some usernames and not there password and want to use them using the service user authentication , in a java standalone or J2EE application.

I can authenticate them using my own login module and without service user, but I am searching if its possible to authenticate them and perform action using the service user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean?

If you want to use some Service Account instead real user while you working with FileNet CE, you just need to create new Security Context with the new Subject, look to samples of connecting to filenet.

If you want to use User authenticated without password you need to use custom LoginModule or TAI (for WebSphere only).